# useSelect in event callback - not retrieving value on time

Tags: block-editor

I tried using useSelect in event callback as described in [block editor handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#useselect), however, I get undefined since value is retrieved later than I need it. I guess I need some kind of extra async function to catch value when is retrieved, or is there some other mechanism not described here?

**Note that I am not using useSelect in a classical way with callback because value can't be retrieved upon component refresh, but on user action**

This code is supposed to check, when certain type of post is selected then retreive it's featured image, otherwise let user select image. Currently I am only logging to the console because I am debugging it.

`SingleImage` is component abstracted away, which lets user select and replace image.

```
import { useBlockProps, URLInput } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import SingleImage from '../../components/singleImage.jsx'
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';

import './editor.scss';

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    const { getEntityRecord } = useSelect('core');
    const urlInputSetter = (url, post) => {
        if (post && ! attributes.imgID) {
            if (post.type === 'virtualne-izlozbe') {
                const record = getEntityRecord('postType', 'virtualne-izlozbe', post.id );
                if (record)
                    console.log(record.featured_media);
                else
                    console.log('empty');
            }
        }
        setAttributes( { link: url, postTitle: (post && post.title) } )
    }

    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <URLInput
                value={ attributes.link }
                onChange={ urlInputSetter }
                label="Link na objavu"
                className="post-link"
            />
            { attributes.postTitle && <div className="post-title">Slika vodi na objavu { attributes.postTitle }</div> }
            <SingleImage
                imgID={attributes.imgID}
                imgURL={attributes.imgURL}
                alt="Slika koja vodi na objavu"
                setImgIdAndUrl={(imgID, imgURL) => setAttributes({imgID, imgURL})}
                title="Izaberi sliku"
                help="Slika koja vodi na objavu"
            />

        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation you posted it says:

**Don’t use useSelect this way when calling the selectors in the render
function because your component won’t re-render on a data change.**

```js
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
 
function Paste( { children } ) {
    const { getSettings } = useSelect( 'my-shop' );
    function onPaste() {
        // Do something with the settings.
        const settings = getSettings();
    }
    return <div onPaste={ onPaste }>{ children }</div>;
}
```

Which is basically how you used and that is why your component is re-rendering when there is a change.

You can use react hooks (useState, useEffect)to resolve this issue. See the code below. I have commented the code to explain the changes. (code is not tested)

```js
import { useBlockProps, URLInput } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import SingleImage from '../../components/singleImage.jsx';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
const { useState, useEffect } = wp.element;
import './editor.scss';

export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
    // Prepare state
    const [post, setPost] = useState();

    // useSelect with a callback, notice the third paramter
    const record = useSelect(
        (select) => {
            return select('core').getEntityRecords(
                'postType',
                'virtualne-izlozbe',
                post.id
            );
        },
        // This is a dependency array, everytime the state of
        // "post" changes, useSelect callback will be called.
        [post]
    );

    // Perfom actions on state change
    useEffect(() => {
        // record value change, do someting
        if (record) {
            console.log(record.featured_media);
        } else {
            console.log('empty');
        }
        // Dependency array, every time record changes the useEffect callback
        // will be called
    }, [record]);

    const urlInputSetter = (url, urlPost) => {
        if (urlPost && !attributes.imgID) {
            if (urlPost.type === 'virtualne-izlozbe') {
                // Change state so the useSelect callback will be triggered
                setPost(urlPost);
            }
        }
        setAttributes({ link: url, postTitle: post && post.title });
    };

    return (
        <div {...useBlockProps()}>
            <URLInput
                value={attributes.link}
                onChange={urlInputSetter}
                label="Link na objavu"
                className="post-link"
            />
            {attributes.postTitle && (
                <div className="post-title">
                    Slika vodi na objavu {attributes.postTitle}
                </div>
            )}
            <SingleImage
                imgID={attributes.imgID}
                imgURL={attributes.imgURL}
                alt="Slika koja vodi na objavu"
                setImgIdAndUrl={(imgID, imgURL) =>
                    setAttributes({ imgID, imgURL })
                }
                title="Izaberi sliku"
                help="Slika koja vodi na objavu"
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: No, that is not true. I do not use getEntityRecord in render function, but in UrlInputSetter callback. And that is exactly how this is supposed to work [from the handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#useselect):

When data is only used in an event callback, the data should not be retrieved
on render, so it may be useful to get the selectors function instead.